# Remove() function not working properly in for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to write a function that when a button is clicked it removes only certain elements from a parent element by looping through its children and then  sets the display property of the parent element to none. Im having an issue where some elements are being deleted and some aren't even though they fit the conditions for being removed.
Here is my code:

```
function closePopUp() {


    var children = document.getElementById('pack-opened').childNodes;

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        const child = children[i];
        if (child.id != "card" && child.id != "close" && child.id != null) {
            child.remove()
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('pack-opened').classList.add('d-none');



}
```

I thought that maybe the problem lies in the fact that most of the children that i want to delete are cloned using the clone function but some of them still get removed and some don't.

Here is the code i used to clone: (res is just a json object with some attributes)

```
for (let j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
        const element = res[j];
        var card = document.getElementById("card")
        var clone = card.cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "card" + j;
        clone.getElementsByClassName("hero-image")[0].src = getPic(element, "portrait_xlarge")
        clone.getElementsByClassName("sup-name")[0].innerHTML = element.name.toUpperCase()
        clone.getElementsByClassName("front-img")[0].setAttribute("style", "background-image:  url(" + "'" + getPic(element, "portrait_xlarge") + "'" + ")   ");
        card.after(clone)
        clone.classList.remove("d-none")

    }
```

Here is the html code that triggers the function, I also tried using an event listener but the result is the same:

```
<div id="pack-opened" class="container-fluid bg-white pack-opened text-center p-5 d-none">
        <div id="card" class=" frame d-none" data-tilt data-tilt-axis="x">
            <div class="img-box rounded-1 "><img class="hero-image" src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="front-img"></div>

                <div class="sup-name"> </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="closebtn"> <button class="btn btn-danger marvred marvel-font" onclick="closePopUp()">CLOSE</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[By logging the children variable before and after removing the child elements this is the result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kly5D.png)

I have tried different methods like remove() and removechild() aswell as using the children collection and the childNodes nodelist. I wonder if the problem lies in the way my html document loads elements and this causes the removal of only some of them.

Comment: Consider what happens to the list of children when you delete a child. The list gets shorter. Where does `i` point then?

Comment: From [MDN childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes): `The read-only childNodes property of the Node interface returns a live NodeList of child nodes [...] Note: The NodeList being live means that its content is changed each time new children are added or removed.`